# R Fill a list of lists with a loop produces an error

Tags: r, nested-lists, data-manipulation

I working on a project that requires me to fill large amounts of data into a list of lists. I keep getting a 'subscript out of bounds' error. I understand what this means, and I've tried to debug, but everything I'm seeing says to me that it should be working.

I've recreated the error through a simplified example below:

```
tl <- list(list())
max <- 3
for (i in 1:max) {
  tl[[i]][[1]] <- 1
  tl[[i]][[2]] <- 2
  tl[[i]][[3]] <- 3
}
```

Running this produces the error `Error in '*tmp*'[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`. Why does this occur? My interpretation is that when 'i' gets to 2, it should jump to the second level of list (which is empty until populated, but this is where the error happens).

Any insights as to why this is happening would be very helpful. Please let me know if I can clarify anything. This is simplified from a project containing much larger lists of lists, but I've tried to keep it simple.

Comment: Or maybe you can try with another scheme: `lapply(1:3, function(i) lapply(1:3, function(j) j))`

Comment: I attempted to modify my code to work with lapply instead of a list, but that created a new problem in a different part of my code. In short, once the list of lists is created and populated, I have to compare a different 1-level list to the elements of the list of lists. I may eventually revisit this depending on how the program develops.

Answer (score 1):

`tl <- list(list())` does not create a list of list, it just creates a list.
Add `tl[[i]]<-list()` inside your for loop to make the a sub list.

```
tl <- list()
max <- 3
for (i in 1:max) {
  #create the sublists
  tl[[i]]<-list()
    tl[[i]][[1]] <- 1
    tl[[i]][[2]] <- 2
    tl[[i]][[3]] <- 3
}
```

Comment: This did the trick. I figured there was something simple I was missing. Thanks for steering in me in the right direction.

Comment: `list(list())` _does_ create a list of a list. A list of length one, with the one entry being an empty list.. The problem is basically that `list()[[1]]` fails.